# PyFPDF, HTMLMixin, Python Unable to print HTML

Tags: python, pyfpdf

I am unable to output an HTML message using [PyFPDF](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  When I attempt to [write the HTML to the PDF document](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write_html/index.html) I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/elcid/Projects/so_test/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    pdf.write_html("<b>Sample HTML</b>")
  File "/Users/elcid/.pyenv/versions/so/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/html.py", line 400, in write_html
    text = h2p.unescape(text) # To deal with HTML entities
AttributeError: 'HTML2FPDF' object has no attribute 'unescape'
```

The offending code:

```py
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.write_html("<b>Sample HTML</b>")
pdf.output("html.pdf")
```

I am using Python 3.9.  Any insight?  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in PyFPDF. Internally, the `write_html` method tries to escape the HTML by calling the `unescape` method of a subclass of Python's `HTMLParser` class, rather than simply calling `html.unescape` as it should.

PyFPDF hasn't been updated in six years and is [no longer actively maintained](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/issues/171). I'd recommend trying its modern fork and successor, [fpdf2](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/).

The [example from the documentation](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/HTML.html) appears to run fine:

```py
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.write_html("""
  <h1>Big title</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Section title</h2>
    <p><b>Hello</b> world. <u>I am</u> <i>tired</i>.</p>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2">PyFPDF/fpdf2 GitHub repo</a></p>
    <p align="right">right aligned text</p>
    <p>i am a paragraph <br />in two parts.</p>
    <font color="#00ff00"><p>hello in green</p></font>
    <font size="7"><p>hello small</p></font>
    <font face="helvetica"><p>hello helvetica</p></font>
    <font face="times"><p>hello times</p></font>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Other section title</h2>
    <ul><li>unordered</li><li>list</li><li>items</li></ul>
    <ol><li>ordered</li><li>list</li><li>items</li></ol>
    <br>
    <br>
    <pre>i am preformatted text.</pre>
    <br>
    <blockquote>hello blockquote</blockquote>
    <table width="50%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="30%">ID</th>
          <th width="70%">Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Alice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
""")
pdf.output("html.pdf")
```

Make sure to uninstall PyFPDF, since they use the same module name.